# How to put squence number in a new column in one sql statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a table(col1, col2, ...) with many legacy data. Then I add a new column `myID` to this table. Then I want to put numbers like 1,2,3,... to this column so that the table data looks like:
(1, ...)
(2, ...)
(3, ...)

After that I want to change this column myID to identity column

How would I use SQL to do this without writing a stored procedure using cursor?

Comment: You cannot alter a column to be an identity column in SQL Server. You would need to create it as identity and use `identity_insert` if you need to insert explicit values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it as identity when you create it and MSSQL will do the rest.

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but got following kind of error:'MyTable' table
- Unable to modify table.  
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MyID', table 'MyDB.dbo.Tmp_MyTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.  Is there any setting I should set it up?

Comment: From what I can understand you didn't make it identity, but you specified that the field is to be not nullable. Try expanding the identity option to see also where the identity starts and what is the counter. Any new field if set identity (only one / table) will be autogenerated by the server.

Comment: Figured it out: to add a new column, no problem, but if you insert a new colum, it won't work.